# Writing a simple for statement program that shows asterisks

Tags: c++, for-loop

i want to create a program that uses two for statements to display the pattern of asterisks shown below.

```
 **
 ****
 ******
 ********
 **********
```

i can make them using quite a few for statements but i only want to use 2 of them, to make it shorter
this is what i have:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
 int row = 1;
 int astrk = 1;

 for ( int row = 1; row < 2; row += 1)
 {
 for ( int astrk = 1; astrk <= 2; astrk += 1)
 cout << '*';
 cout << endl;
 }// end for
 for ( int row = 1; row < 2; row += 1)
 {
 for ( int astrk = 1; astrk <= 4; astrk +=1)
 cout << '*';
 cout << endl;
 }//end for
 for ( int row = 1; row < 2; row += 1)
 {
 for ( int astrk = 1; astrk <= 6; astrk += 1)
 cout << '*';
 cout << endl;
 }// end for
 for ( int row = 1; row < 2; row += 1)
 {
 for ( int astrk = 1; astrk <= 8; astrk += 1)
 cout << '*';
 cout << endl;
 }// end for
 for ( int row = 1; row < 2; row += 1)
 {
 for ( int astrk = 1; astrk <= 10; astrk += 1)
 cout << '*';
 cout << endl;
 }// end for

 return 0;
 }
```

help please? :)

Comment: **Hint**: You have five loops here, one for each row. And they're barely loops, since each iterates only once. And how do they differ? Only in the upper limit to `astrk`, which goes `2, 4, 6, 8, 10`. Does that suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite this using two `for` loops, once controlling the rows, and the other one controlling the column.

You have 5 rows, and on each row, you have 2, 4, 6, etc... stars.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) // five rows
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= i * 2; ++j) // we have 2 stars for each row number -> 2, 4, 6, etc...
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Try to understand your problem, figure out a solution on paper and then try to implement it, it will be way simpler if you're learning how to program.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an outer loop for the number of lines, and an inner loop for the asterisks. When the inner loop is done printing the asterisks, the outer loop prints a newline, and increases the asterisk count.

In pseudo-code:

```
for (from one to the number of lines)
{
    for (one to the number of asterisks)
    {
        print an asterisk
    }

    print a newline
    increase number of asterisks
}
```

Comment: i had tried that way and this is what i came up with:                                                                     #include <iostream>
      #include <iomanip>
      using namespace std;

      int main()
      {
      int row = 1;
      int astrk = 1;

      for ( int row = 1; row < 6; row += 1)
      {
      for ( int astrk = 1; astrk <= 13; astrk += 1)
      cout << '*';
      cout << endl;
      }// end for

Comment: @jewport101, then why does your code have a loop for each line instead of one loop for all lines?

Comment: @jewport101 That will print five lines of 13 asterisks each. The upper limit of asterisks must be a variable, that you increase in the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Note the pattern:

Line 1 has 2 asterisks,
Line 2 has 4 asterisks,
Line 3 has 6 asterisks,
...

The number of asterisks to print is determined by multiplying the line number by 2.

Like emartel showed, you can dynamically determine how many times the inner for loop will run by basing the inner for loop's test expression upon the current i value of the outer loop (line number) multiplied by 2 (number of single asterisks to print).

Most problems like these will come down to having the inner for loop use the outer for loops counter value in some clever way to print the desired output pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out the following code

```
  for(int i=0;i<6;i++){//used to print out rows

        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){used to print asterisk in each row
                cout<<"**";
                }
        cout<<endl;
        }
```

for more details visit: http://include.site40.net/aasterics.php