# Problem during creating Pyramid Star Patterns in PHP

Tags: php

Question :
[image]

My Code :

```
   <html\>


  
    Enter the number of rows:   
      
  


<?php   
    if($_POST)  
    {     
        $row = $_POST['row'];   
    
        if(!is_numeric($row))  
        {  
            echo "Make sure you enter a NUMBER";  
            return;   
        }   
    
        else  
        {  
            for($row=0;$row<=1;$row++){ 
    for($j=0;$j<=$row;$j++){ echo "#"; } echo ""; }}}?>
```

The problem is it's showing only two rows

I expected as shown in the photo

Comment: It's because your loop is only for 2 iterations (`$row<=1;`). You should change that part

Comment: fyi, `<html\>` is not a valid html closing tag. It should be `</html>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13522791/2943403

Comment: https://3v4l.org/cOK8o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$row = 10;
for($i=0;$i<=$row;$i++){ 
for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++){ echo "#"; } echo "<br>"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the `$row` variable.
Also, you don't need the `else` since you are returning in case the `if(!is_numeric)` is true;

This should do it.

```
if(isset($_POST['row'])) {     
    $rows = $_POST['row'];   

    if(!is_numeric($rows))  
    {  
        echo "Make sure you enter a NUMBER";  
        return;   
    }

    for($row=0;$row<=$rows;$row++){ 

        for($j=0;$j<=$row;$j++){ 
            echo "#"; 
        } 
        
        echo "\n";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: For readability I would suggest choosing another name for the `$row` variable then. Perhaps `$i`.

Comment: well, each iteration of the first `for` is actually a row, that's why I left it as `$row`. But `$i` can work as well

Comment: Yeah, that is correct, however (and this is also based on personal preference) using something else then `$row` (or `$rows`) for that matter would improve readability. But I'm not here to argue.

Comment: @brunerPhone I agree to that as well. I think the variable names is a thing for the OP to figure out. Good observations re readability. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the PHP function [str_repeat](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.str-repeat.php) to simplify the script.
This would only take 1 loop, so you don't get confused with the variable names.

```
$row = 10;
$i   = 1;
while ($i <= $row)
{
    echo str_repeat("#", $i); echo "\n";
    $i ++;
}
```

Working Example [here](https://paiza.io/projects/gMbWYbLDxZqIbzisOrAifw).